# debugging: what is the mysterious app01.exe

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I am debugging an application on win8.1 using a legacy debugger (VS6, sorry about that). I have noticed that when debugging starts, there is a mysterious "module" loaded first of all:

Loaded 'APP01.EXE', no matching symbolic information found.

Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', no matching symbolic information found.

...

APP01 is not the name of the program being debugged. It isn't a program I can find running or installed on that system, so what on earth can it be? Can it be a [compatibility shim](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2011/06/17/demystifying-shims-or-using-the-app-compat-toolkit-to-make-your-old-stuff-work-with-your-new-stuff.aspx) for VS6?

Comment: I see some google hits, looks like malware to me.

Comment: no, false alarm. When I use windbg to debug the same application, the mysterious App01.exe disappears and in its place (same mapped address) is ntdll.dll. FUnny that it appears without a full path like all the other system DLLs... anyway sorry for timewasting :)

Answer (score 0):

I just also noticed a similar message when debugging my application with **VC6**.

I am making a system call to load an application in a loop and each time I make the call, I see another similar message, so I get multiple messages directly related to making a call to the C function system() to launch an exe from my program....

```
Loaded 'APP01.EXE', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'APP02.EXE', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'APP03.EXE', no matching symbolic information found.
Loaded 'APP04.EXE', no matching symbolic information found.
```

For this reason I suspect this is the result of C realizing that an EXE was launched from within your application.  Did you also use system or fork or some such thing in your program?